# Docker unable to login using _json_key_base64, but can login with _json_key

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

I saved the json key file to a local file `jsonkey`, then login to GCR using it. Following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#json-key), I should be able to login using either json key or base64 encoded json key.

However `_json_key_base64` doesn't work, only `_json_key` works.

Here's my command:

```
$ cat jsonkey | base64 | docker login -u _json_key_base64 --password-stdin \
https://asia.gcr.io
Error response from daemon: Get "https://asia.gcr.io/v2/": unauthorized: Not Authorized.

$ cat jsonkey | docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin \ 
https://asia.gcr.io
Login Succeeded
```

Anyone knows why?

Comment: Will you use that mode for you own development environment, or for a third party CI/CD pipeline?

Comment: I try to use it on my CI/CD pipeline. Is there any different between them?

Comment: No, just to be sure that there were no other solution than using a service account key file. it's not really a bad practice as long as your CI/CD is not running on Google Cloud! In any case, take care of that secret file! About your issue, how did you encode your JSON key file in base 64?

Comment: I used `base64` OS built in to encode it, same result on Cyberchef.

Comment: Looks like it's a bug on gcloud itself. I can login with `_json_key_base64` to https://pkg.dev but not https://gcr.io.

Comment: Do you have an option to generate b64 content with padding? It could be the issue.

Comment: Tried that, still didn't work. It seems to be a bug on GCR, because I can use `_json_key_base64` on Gcloud Artifact Registry but not CR, so my base64 key is valid but GCR does not parse this yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bug was raised to GCP team, this feature is not supported in Container Registry.

> [It is not possible for users to login to Container Registry through a _json_key_base_64 as Container Registry does not support this type of key. If you need this functionality, please consider migrating to Artifact Registry which does support it.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/273870217#comment3)

They also edited [the related documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#json-key), `_json_key_base64` is not listed as supported anymore, only `_json_key`.